# How to set Redux's initialState to NULL?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm coding ( Slice ) from Redux, but I need the ( initialState ) to be NULL, what's the best way to do this? I tried inserting the comma but it didn't work.

**My Code:**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const slice = createSlice({
    name: 'initial',
    
    initialState,
    
    reducers: {
        ADDS(state, actions) {
            return {
                ...state, 
                product: actions.payload,
            } 
        }
    }
});

export const { ADDS } = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;
```

**My Error:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: initialState is not defined
    at ./src/redux/slice.js (slice.js:6:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/App.js (bundle.js:21:70)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/index.js (UI.jsx:3:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Put all information in your question post, please. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Just set it to null?

```
const initialState = null;
export const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'initial',
  initialState,
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 shorthand notations `let obj = {x};` is short for `let obj = {x : x}`. So this will only work if `x` is defined. Otherwise the code will throw an error since `x` is undefined.

```js
//let x = 2; //uncomment this to see
console.log({x});
```

You can do this:

```
export const slice = createSlice({
    name: 'initial',
    
    initialState : null,
    
    reducers: {
        ADDS(state, actions) {
            return {
                ...state, 
                product: actions.payload,
            } 
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the doc for [shorthand notations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions)